# Embedding an active pdf into a webpage?

Tags: pdf

I have an active pdf with editable form elements I would like to display. The goal is to have user fill out the pdf then click a 'submit' button and the edited pdf would be emailed to me. I tried the following code, but while the form is visible it is not editable (at least in firefox).

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="form.pdf">
   <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
</object>
```

How can I dispaly an *editable* pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox relies on (I think it still does) [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to be able to display PDFs in the browser. It looks like they have an open issue for supporting fillable/editable forms on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1459).

It looks like the [PDFium](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/) project has support for Acroforms and that they may even have support for XFA forms given the discussions on the mailing list.

The web browser that your users are using to view the web page the PDF in either needs to know how to support forms on its own or you will need to include support through one of these projects on your own.